# Generate rows and insert into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've following table

```
CREATE TABLE public.af01
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('af01_id_seq'::regclass),
  idate timestamp without time zone,
  region text,
  city text,
  vtype text,
  vmake text,
  vmodel text,
  vregno text,
  intime time without time zone,
  otime time without time zone,
  vstatus boolean,
  remarks text,
  vowner text
);
```

I need to add data into it.This data should be for 1 Year, (data from `01-01-2016` to `31-12-2016`). in a single date can have 5 entries,
 `Region` column must have 3 values (`Central,Western,Eastern`),
 `City` column must have 3 values(`City1`,`City2`,`City3`)
 `vtype` column is the Vehicle type for example `Heavy,light,Other`.
 `vmake` column is the manufacturer `Audi,Nissan,Toyota,Hyundai,GMC` etc.
 `vregno` this column is for vechicle registration number and it should be unique (Ex.reg no `CFB 4587`).
 `intime` any random time in day('10:15 AM'). 
`otime` this column should be `intime`+ 5 or 10 or 15 or 20.`vstatus` column should have `True` or `false`.

I've ended up with this select query to generate date rows

```
select '2013-01-01'::date + (n || ' days')::interval days
  from generate_series(0, 365) n;
```

and

to generate first part of the Vehicle regno.

```
   SELECT substring(string_agg (substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil (random() * 62)::integer, 1), ''),1,3) t
    FROM   generate_series(0,45);
```

expected output;

```
id idate      region  city  vtype          vmake  vmodel vregno   intime              otime               vstatus remarks vowner 
-- ---------- ------- ----- -------------- ------ ------ -------- ------------------- ------------------- ------- ------- ------ 
1  2016-01-01 Central City1 Heavy Vechicle Nissan Model1 NGV 4578 12:15:00  12:30:00 1       NULL    Tom    
2  2016-01-01 Western City1 Light          Audi   S3     BFR 4587 10:20:00 10:40:00 1       NULL    Jerry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

r_dates relation is just simple way to generate dates in ranges.

other_const and max_const are arrays and its length respectively for population. region[(random() * region_max)::int2 + 1] - choose element in array by random

```
INSERT INTO af01 (idate, region, city, vtype, vmake, vregno, intime, otime, vstatus) 
SELECT cd, r, c, v, vm, rn, intime, intime + len as otime, status
FROM (
      WITH r_dates AS (
           SELECT generate_series('2013-01-01'::date, '2013-12-31'::date, '1 day'::interval) as cd
      ), other_const AS  (
           SELECT '{Central,Western,Eastern}'::text[] AS region,
                  '{City1,City2,City3}'::text[] as cities,
                  '{Heavy,light,Other}'::text[] as vehicles,
                  '{Audi,Nissan,Toyota,Hyundai,GMC}'::text[] as vmakes,
                  '{5,10,15,20}'::int4[] AS lengths,
                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'::text AS regnosrc
      ), max_const AS  (
           SELECT array_upper(region, 1) - 1 AS region_max,
                  array_upper(cities, 1) - 1 AS cities_max,
                  array_upper(vehicles, 1) - 1 AS vehicles_max,
                  array_upper(vmakes, 1) - 1 AS vmakes_max,
                  array_upper(lengths, 1) - 1 AS lengths_max
        FROM other_const
      ) 
      SELECT cd,
             region[(random() * region_max)::int2 + 1] AS r,
             cities[(random() * cities_max)::int2 + 1] AS c,
             vehicles[(random() * vehicles_max)::int2 + 1] AS v,
             vmakes[(random() * vmakes_max)::int2 + 1] AS vm,
             (
                 SELECT string_agg(s, '')
                   FROM (
                         SELECT substr(regnosrc, (random() * (length(regnosrc) - 1))::int4 + 1, 1) AS s
                           FROM generate_series(1, 3)
                       ) AS a
               )
                  || lpad(((random() * 9999)::int8)::text, 4, '0') AS rn,
              '00:00:00'::time + (((random() * 24 * 60)::int8)::text || 'min')::interval AS intime,
              ((lengths[(random() * lengths_max)::int2 + 1])::text || 'min')::interval AS len,
              random() > 0.5 AS status
         FROM r_dates, other_const, max_const, generate_series(1, 5)
   ) AS A
```

Comment: Is there anyway to have a relationship with Region and City ? Ex. City1 must be in Western Region

Comment: if you have table with cities you can just: `SELECT cityname FROM cities ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`

Comment: I don't have a table  atm, but I will create one and do it like that